# Configure mouse in tmux on OSX

Tags: macos, tmux

It seems that mouse support changed in one of the recent versions of tmux and every article I am finding on the subject uses outdated settings. All I want to be able to do is use my mouse to scroll when in scroll mode and use it to copy/paste with the left button like it usually does in a terminal. Unfortunately, if I set `set -g mouse on` the copy/paste doesn't work and if I set it to off, scroll doesn't work. I am on OSX 10.12 Sierra if that makes a difference and I am using the default Terminal app.

Answer (score 13):

One quick way to get copy-paste functionality back using the mouse is to disable "Mouse Reporting"; see the menu item `View > Allow Mouse Reporting` in *Terminal.app*. The default keyboard shortcut is <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>, so a possible workflow is:

1. Hit <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> to toggle off mouse reporting.
2. Highlight text with mouse as usual, copy with <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>, or paste with middle-click.
3. Hit <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> to restore tmux's mouse functionality.

Alternatively, hold down the <kbd>fn</kbd> key to temporarily obtain the same functionality, as noted in the answer from @yaroslavpalamar.

### Multi-pane solution

The comments pointed to an issue with this solution when using multiple panes. This requires a fix from within tmux, in order to simultaneously zoom the pane and allow copy/paste with the mouse. To do that, we can augment the solution pointed to by @MadWombat by adding the line below to the config.

In your `~/.tmux.conf` file (or `/etc/tmux.conf`):

```
bind-key m set mouse \; resize-pane -Z
```

Then <kbd>prefix</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd> is a toggle: hit it once to zoom the pane and  allow copy/paste with the mouse, hit it again regain the former functionality. Note this works fine with a single pane as well -- the zoom part of the command has no effect in that case.

Comment: I have done something similar but in the tmux config. I use `bind-key m set mouse` and then I can switch between mouse scrolling and mouse selecting using that binding.

Comment: Using this does not really work, it copies text across tmux panes, if they are side-by-side for example, which is probably never the behavior you want.

Comment: @FlorianBienefelt yes, if you have side-by-side panes open, you're limited to single-line copies or you'll copy the text from both panes. In that case you'll need to zoom your pane before the copy.

Comment: @FlorianBienefelt See the edit for a solution that works with multiple panes

Comment: You are a life-saver my dude! Cmd-R once, Cmd-R twice! This is so much easier than dumping tons of lines into the config ile which are probably going to be obsoleted in a few months anyway.

Comment: And tmux resurrect uses Command + Shift + R as it's hotkey which is why some people like myself originally ran into this issue!

Answer (score 10):

In my case **fn** button + mouse works fine for text selection. 
After selection need to press **cmd+c** for copying and paste with **cmd+v**.

Comment: or just fn-middleclick for pasting after selection

Comment: This doesn't work for me if trying to select text after having scrolled back in the buffer. In that case, @spinup's answer did: scroll, cmd-R, select (without fn), copy, cmd-R.

Answer (score 5):

tmux changed mouse behaviour moving from v2.0 to v2.1.

You can find more information reading tmux's github repository [issue 145 description.](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/145)

I don't use this anymore, but this fixed mouse handling for me after moving to v2.1:

```
# Handling mouse
set -g mouse on
# Fix Mouse Scrolling: https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/145
bind -n WheelUpPane if-shell -F -t = "#{mouse_any_flag}" "send-keys -M" "if -Ft= '#{pane_in_mode}' 'send-keys -M' 'select-pane -t=; copy-mode -e; send-keys -M'"
bind -n WheelDownPane select-pane -t= \; send-keys -M
```

With this settings you can select using the mouse and the Option (alt) key and then use Cmd-C to copy the selection.

Comment: Does't work. I just tried to add this to my config and I cannot select. Without option key I get the weird brown selection from the tmux scroll mode and wit option key I don't get any selection at all.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried many different solutions but the only working (scrolling with mouse and possibility to copy/paste using usual `CMD+C/V`) for me was the one stated over [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/318281/how-to-copy-and-paste-with-a-mouse-with-tmux/318285#318285?newreg=411ce6a657fb4665a7d1c0650bca6c43):

i.e. put this inside `~/.tmux.conf`:

```
# macOS only
set -g mouse on
bind -n WheelUpPane if-shell -F -t = "#{mouse_any_flag}" "send-keys -M" "if -Ft= '#{pane_in_mode}' 'send-keys -M' 'select-pane -t=; copy-mode -e; send-keys -M'"
bind -n WheelDownPane select-pane -t= \; send-keys -M
bind -n C-WheelUpPane select-pane -t= \; copy-mode -e \; send-keys -M
bind -T copy-mode-vi    C-WheelUpPane   send-keys -X halfpage-up
bind -T copy-mode-vi    C-WheelDownPane send-keys -X halfpage-down
bind -T copy-mode-emacs C-WheelUpPane   send-keys -X halfpage-up
bind -T copy-mode-emacs C-WheelDownPane send-keys -X halfpage-down

# To copy, left click and drag to highlight text in yellow, 
# once you release left click yellow text will disappear and will automatically be available in clibboard
# # Use vim keybindings in copy mode
setw -g mode-keys vi
# Update default binding of `Enter` to also use copy-pipe
unbind -T copy-mode-vi Enter
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi Enter send-keys -X copy-pipe-and-cancel "pbcopy"
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi MouseDragEnd1Pane send-keys -X copy-pipe-and-cancel "pbcopy"
```

then run tmux command `source-file ~/.tmux.conf` (by typing `CTRL+B`, followed by `:`)

Answer (score 0):

You can hold `shift` when selecting text this way it won't invoke copy and paste mode.

https://awhan.wordpress.com/2012/04/18/tmux-copy-paste-with-mouse/

> you will notice that you are not able to select text at all.
>   **The solution is to use the shift key.**
>   Hold down the shift key and then left click and drag across the target text. If you want to now paste the selected text back in to xterm, you must also hold down the shift key and then middle click in order to paste the text. This is not mentioned in the tmux man pages so i do not think this is a tmux feature. guess this has something to do with xterm, but i m not sure.

https://superuser.com/questions/300060/tmux-and-text-selection-with-mouse-through-putty

Comment: This is not what happens. If I just select text with the mouse it turns on tmux scroll mode and selects the text, but I cannot actually copy/paste anything even with keyboard shortcuts. If I press shift, I cannot select at all.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `set -g mouse on` as specified above works to use the mouse for scrolling.

On Linux the shift button works to allow the normal mouse selection and copy/paste, but on Mac it seems to be the Alt button, give that a try (it works for me using tmux on iTerm2).

Comment: Alt/Opt is specific to iTerm2, apparently for Terminal.app it's Fn.

Answer (score 0):

On OSX and `tmux 3.0a` with `set -g mouse on` in your `tmux.conf`, you can use `ctrl-b [` then a mouse drag to select text. After which you should be able to paste with `ctrl-b ]`.